# Asp.net Place Order to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, websites

I am looking for a solution in which **asp.net web page** place an **order** to my store. I have seen some solutions they are using the **wsdl** reference which is now obsolete . can anyone please help me in sharing it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento api to create order. Call Magento's REST API with it's required payload and order will be created in Magento. Look at the documentation here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-order.html